# Получения постов по ключевым словам

Tags: python

Всем привет!
Цель:

Получить  при парсинге вк все посты в которых содержатся ключевые слова(их около 15)

Пробовал делать проверку через if но выходили только именно ключевые слова вместо целого поста

кусок кода парсера ниже:

```
data = response.json()
        items = data["response"]["items"]


            for item in items:
                text_post = item.get("text").strip() #Получаем текст поста
                url_sec = str(item['from_id']) + '_' + str(item['id'])
                url = f"https://vk.com/{x}?w=wall{url_sec}"
                print(f"{url}\n {text_post}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно апи вк взять

```
import requests

url = "https://api.vk.com/method/wall.search"
params = {
    "access_token": ACCESS_TOKEN,
    "v": "V",
    "q": "keyword1|keyword2|keyword3",
    "count": 100 # Максимальное количество постов в ответе
}
response = requests.get(url, params=params)
data = response.json()
items = data["response"]["items"]

for item in items:
    text_post = item.get("text").strip() #Получаем текст поста
    url_sec = str(item['from_id']) + '_' + str(item['id'])
    url = f"https://vk.com/{x}?w=wall{url_sec}"
    print(f"{url}\n {text_post}")
```

Comment: Спасибо, не видел такого метода API, В следующий раз буду изучать внимательнее

Comment: Добрый день, вчера этот метод работал и выводил данные при парсинге но сегодня когда я добавил в список групп (которые нужно парсить) около 100 шт. и теперь мне этот метод возращает пустой [items] Как быть в таком случае?

Comment: Интересный вопрос, надо читать документацию) или как вариант поочередный  перебор делать